# When i trying to remove elements in a list it is not working can anyone explain me why this is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code I have used and it is not removing last zero it is skipping

```
x = [1,2,3,0,0,0]


for I in x:
    if I==0:
        x.remove(I)
print(x)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 0]
```

so from the output the last zero is not removing why

Comment: As an aside, please always use the generic [python] tag for all python-related questions

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use this simple list comprehension.

```
x = [1,2,3,0,0,0]
y=[i for i in x if i != 0]
print(y)
```

You'll get a new list (y) with the 0 removed, while the x is preserved in it's original state.

```
[1, 2, 3]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

For more study on list.remove(), [check this](https://www.techiedelight.com/remove-all-occurrences-item-list-python/)
List.remove() does not remove all occurrances

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), list.remove removes first element whose value matches given number.

So, when first '0' at index 3 is removed, the new list is `[1,2,3,0,0]` with the list iteration index at 4. The following 0 (which was at index 4 in original list) moves back one place and is getting skipped. This can be seen with following code:

```py
x = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
for id, i in enumerate(x):
    print(id, i)
    if i == 0:
        print(x, i)
        x.remove(i)

print(x)
```

In this, every second element is missed, and final x is `[0, 0, 0]`

As for what is correct way to do this, list comprehension is a good way, as answered by Anand: `x = [i for i in x if i!=0]`